# finding the index of word and its distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text-mining

hello there ive been trying to code a script that finds the distance the word `one` to the other `one` in a text but the code somehow doesnt work well...

```
import re

#dummy text
words_list = ['one']
long_string = "are marked by one  the ()meta-characters. two They group together the expressions contained one inside them, and you can one repeat the contents of a group with a repeating qualifier, such as there one"

striped_long_text = re.sub(' +', ' ',(long_string.replace('\n',' '))).strip()
length = []

index_items = {}

for item in words_list :
    text_split = striped_long_text.split('{}'.format(item))[:-1]

    for space in text_split:
        if space:
            length.append(space.count(' ')-1)

print(length)
```

**dummy Text :**

> are marked by one  the ()meta-characters. two They group together the expressions contained one inside them, and you can one repeat the contents of a group with a repeating qualifier, such as there one

so what im trying to do is that find the exact distance the word `one` has to its next similar `one` in text as you see , this code works well with in some exceptions... if the first text has the word `one` after 2-3 words the index starts to the counting from the start of the text and this will fail the output but for example if add the word `one` at the start of the text the code will work fine...

**Output of the code vs what it should be :**

`result = [2, 9, 5, 13]`
`expected result = [ 9, 5, 13]`

Comment: Since you `.split()` over the word `one`, the part before the first occurrence will also be checked. The same would happen with the last part of the text if `one` weren't the last word of the text. You want to skip the first and the last part, apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, using `itertools.groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

words_list = ["one"]
long_string = "are marked by one  the ()meta-characters. two They group together the expressions contained one inside them, and you can one repeat the contents of a group with a repeating qualifier, such as there one"

for w in words_list:
    out = [
        (v, sum(1 for _ in g))
        for v, g in groupby(long_string.split(), lambda k: k == w)
    ]

    # check first and last occurence:
    if out and out[0][0] is False:
        out = out[1:]

    if out and out[-1][0] is False:
        out = out[:-1]

    out = [length for is_word, length in out if not is_word]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[9, 5, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't ask questions in comments yet, but if you want exactly to use regular expressions, than this can help you:

```
import re

def forOneWord(word):
    length = []
    lastIndex = -1
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[i].lower() == word:
            if lastIndex != -1:
                length.append(i - lastIndex - 1)
            lastIndex = i
    return length

def forWordsList(words_list):
    for i in range(len(words_list)):  # Make all words lowercase
        words_list[i] = words_list[i].lower()
        
    length = [[] for i in range(len(words_list))]
    lastIndex = [-1 for i in range(len(words_list))]
    for i in range(len(words)):  # For all words in string
        for j in range(len(words_list)):  # For all words in list
            if words[i].lower() == words_list[j]:
                if lastIndex[j] != -1:  # This means that this is not the first match
                    length[j].append(i - lastIndex[j] - 1)
                lastIndex[j] = i
    return length
    

words_list = ['one' , 'the', 'a']
long_string = "are marked by one  the ()meta-characters. two They group together the expressions contained one inside them, and you can one repeat the contents of a group with a repeating qualifier, such as there one"

words = re.findall(r"(\w[\w!-]*)+", long_string)

print(forOneWord('one'))
print(forWordsList(words_list))
```

There are two functions: one just for single-word search and another to search by list. Also if it is not necessary to use RegEx, I can improve this solution in terms of performance if you want so.